# How do i use an image behind auth in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I know about the `CachedNetworkImage` package but that just says invalid image format while it works trough `curl` code for that:

```dart
return CachedNetworkImage(
  httpHeaders: {'Cookie': 'session=${snapshot.data!}'},
    imageUrl: '${glob.appUrl}pfp',
    progressIndicatorBuilder: (context, url, downloadProgress) =>
      CircularProgressIndicator(
        value: downloadProgress.progress,
      ),
    errorWidget: (context, url, error) {
      return const Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Icon(
              Icons.error,
              color: CupertinoColors.systemRed,
            ),
            Text('Error processing the profile picture!'),
          ],
        ),
      );
    });
```

I must provide the session in a cookie there is no other way. Is there some alternate solution or am i doing it wrong?